# Microservices architecture versioning on periodic releases

Tags: continuous-integration, microservices, release, versioning, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best practices to manage versioning in microservices based architecture with periodic releases.

Currently our system is decomposed into multiple different repositories:

- Frontend
- Backend
- Database
- API gateway
- Docker-compose-env

Each of these components must be developed, built, tested, containerized and deployed independently. But the release cycles are synchronized and periodic. Docker-compose-env project contains the environment definition to start all compatible service versions for development and integration testing purpose.

Current versioning strategy is as follows:

1. Each commit to `master` branch is tagged with a *semantic version* and pushed to docker registry (semantic tags are used to track dependencies during development cycle)
2. Each merge commit to persistent `release` branch is tagged with a *release tag* and pushed to docker registry (release tags are used to synchronize project versions together for quarterly release)

`master` is the trunk, and periodic release build is initiated by PR from `master` to `release`.

[image]

I'm skeptical if this the best way to manage versions with microservices based architecture on periodic releases. Any feedback or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> Each of these components must be developed, built, tested, containerized and deployed *independently*. But the release cycles are *synchronized* and periodic.

There is a contradiction here. Microservices mostly solve an organizational problem - the main point is that teams should be able to work **independently** as much as possible.

Synchronization between teams is what make them slow. This can happen in different ways, e.g. waiting for another version to be deployed in a shared test environment, or using the same shared database schema, or making releases at the same time.

> I'm skeptical if this the best way to manage versions with microservices based architecture on periodic releases.

Try to avoid "synchronized releases", instead make sure to not break any contracts between the services (e.g. no breaking API changes). Try to release more often, you want to *work in small batches* to reduce the risk with deployments and changes. Try to not pile of a bunch of changes, deploy continuously - Continuous Delivery.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I was curious if there's a recommended procedure for making an API breaking change. What's a reasonable way of making contract revisions?

Comment: @financial_physician You should not break things for your clients. You can add a `/v2/` API and let the clients know about it. You still need to serve `/v1/` until no clients use it anymore. It might help to monitor usage of the API versions using e.g. metrics.

Answer (score 2):

**Release cycles are syncronized**

I think the fact that you need to do a synchronized release of all services at the same time could be an indicator that the coupling between your services is higher then it should be and probably the way you are managing it can be improved.

The question is how can you design your development teams working on different micro-services so that when they introduce changes and they do not break each others micro-service?

**Versioning and managing changes**

There are 2 aspects which are important for this to work and they are:

1. Versioning and how you implement and work with versioning.
2. Team Communication. Communication between teams when introducing breaking changes.

**What do I mean by this?**

**First about versioning**. Your micro-services are communicating with each other.
Regardless of the fact that the communication is sync or async using Rest(or SOAP or gRPC or other) or Messaging(Queues) they need to rely on some Contracts. Those Contracts will be some API Contracts(in terms of Java/C# classes/interfaces). They need to be stable as they can be used by other micro-services.

Suggestion: I would suggest to do versioning of the micro-service independent from the versioning of the Contracts.
Example:

- Micro-service order-micro-service could be at latest version v1.0.0 and Contracts order-micro-service-contracts at version v1.0.0 as well.
- Micro-service customer-micro-service could be at latest version v3.0.0 but Contracts customer-micro-service-contracts could be at version v2.2.1.
- Micro-service product-micro-service could be at latest version v3.0.0 and Contracts product-micro-service-contracts could be at version v4.0.0.

As you can see from the example above the version from the Micro-service and its corresponding exposed Contracts can be the same but they can also differ. The reason is simply that you can do changes on the micro-service(some internal business logic change) without changing the Contracts. And you can also do changes on the Contracts without changing the micro-service logic. Usually changes happens on both of them in the same time. You update some api business logic for which you adjust the exposed Contract. But sometimes a MAJOR change in the micro-service logic is not necessary a breaking or MAJOR change on the Contracts. As you see this gives you great flexibility. The benefit of this is not only flexibility but also the fact that a micro-service-A will only be dependent on micro-service-B-contracts and not the micro-service-B itself. This is just a suggestion you can also use one version for micro-service and its exposed Contracts.

**Now about team communication**. By this I mean if you have an organization where you have multiple teams working on different areas of the system and each team is responsible for one or more micro-services from an particular Domain.

If you are using the Semantic versioning like MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH for example v1.3.5 then you can do it in the following way.
There are a couple of things which are important to consider:

- **Contracts PATCH/MINOR change**
  A change which is a PATCH or MINOR change version upgrade should not be a breaking change and should always be **backwards compatible** for the consumers who use those contracts. This means that you should ensure that upgrading from version 1.3.0 to 1.4.0 should not be a problem to the consumer regardless of the fact if he upgraded to 1.4.0 or stayed on 1.3.0 for a little longer. Ideally all consumer should update to latest version but even if they don't for some period they will not be broken by the change. For example a change for which you will do that kind of upgrade would be adding new Contract model or updating existing model with new not mandatory fields, or increasing accepted string length from a field from 20 to 50 or similar.
- **Contracts MAJOR or breaking change**
  Is usually a big change which can also be breaking change. If it is a breaking change then we need some team process in place. The teams who use those contracts need to be notified that the change will happen upfront and even when releasing the new version a bridging period of couple weeks(or sprints) should be ensured where both versions of contracts will work(old and new). This will give the affected teams/micro-services enough time to upgrade and adjust their services. After that the backwards compatibility compromise Contracts/code can be deprecated. Sometimes for some cases a solution for a breaking change Contract change is introducing a complete new version of that Model(class) and not do a hard change on the same Model. For example you could have a CustomerModel class and then introduce CustomerModelV2 and remove the old CustomerModel class after some period. This is a common situation where you have a Contract Model for an Event(Message from a queue) like: CustomerCreated. You can have CustomerCreated and CustomerCreatedV2. You can publish both messages for a particular time period until the consumers adopt and deprecate(stop publishing the event and removing the Contract model) the CustomerCreated event. This depends on your particular business logic or case.
- **Micro-service changes**
  Regardless of the fact that the change is just a bug fix, small change or a big change in the service if your versioning is separate from the from the Contracts it should not be affecting the other micro-services, at least not from the contract managing prospective. Doing versioning updates on micro-service only gives you the possibility to deploy it independently.

**Independent and separate deployments of micro-services**

If you apply the above advice's you will come closer to the situation where you can deploy micro-services independently and without synchronized periods where all services have do be deployed at once.

One of the biggest advantages of using micro-services is being able to deploy micro-services independent from other parts of the system so if you have a chance to do that you should go for it.

> Each of these components must be developed, built, tested,
> containerized and deployed independently. But the release cycles are
> synchronized and periodic.

Since you already develop, build and tested independently you could also do the release independently.

I know that all those suggested changes are not only technical but also organizational changes like team communication, team setup and so on. But usually when working with big system using micro-services it a compromise between those 2 worlds and trying to find the best process and solution for your Organization and Business.